# HPX Examples throwing "failed to insert update_agas_cache_action into typename to id registry" exception

Tags: hpx

I'm new to HPX and trying to build it on Ubuntu 22.04. However after compiling all the examples terminate with:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'hpx::detail::exception_with_info<hpx::exception>'
  what():  failed to insert update_agas_cache_action into typename to id registry.: HPX(invalid_status)
```

I have tried both the release-1.9.X and master branch on github. I have tried compiling with both HPX_WITH_MALLOC=tcmalloc and system. Does anyone have any idea what i'm doing wrong?